# How to in-build wysiwyg editor in a self-build joomla component

Tags: joomla

I know there are some code to get the editor in joomla itself like

```
    <?php
      $editor = JFactory::getEditor();
             echo $editor->display('description', $row->description, '550', '400', '60', '20', false);
?>
```

But after i submit the form, the content will go back to plain text.

I must miss out something, hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code at action page to get value. Hope it helps.

```
$description = JRequest::getVar('description', 'default value goes here', 'post','validation type',JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML);
```

Comment: Could you please describe more? You mean at the model file, i add in this code, and bind it to database?

Comment: Yes, I think in model file you will find code like $post = JRequest::get("post"); here after this you need to add like below code:
$post['description'] = JRequest::getVar('description', 'default value goes here', 'post','validation type',JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML);

Comment: hey, how to add the validation to the description input, which means if the input is empty the data won't be passed to database? i changed the 'validation type' to 'required', but there is no effect. all others work fine.